# Using EWS API to access an Email Inbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to access the contents of an email inbox on Exchange 2013 using the EWS Managed API.

Although I can bind the mailbox to a Folder object. When I try to access the emails I get the exception:

- $exception  {"The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."} Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException

  ```
      ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
      service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
      service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@domain.co.uk");

      Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("email@domain.co.uk");


      FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb);

      Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, fid);

      FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(new ItemView(100));
  ```

The exception is thrown on the last line above.

The Exchange server is running cu16 so the microsoft advice here is useless:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/3006861/-the-smtp-address-has-no-mailbox-associated-with-it-error-when-you-acc

**Update**

The problem was found to be the result of using credentials from an Office 365 account to access the Exchange mailbox.

This was resolved by creating and accessing the mailbox from a new Exchange account.

Comment: Have you tried `service.FindItems(WellKnwonFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try that I get the same exception.

Comment: Are you sure the user has access to the mailbox you are trying read from?

Comment: Yes, I can add the mailbox in outlook. Also in the code above I was able to bind the inbox folder using the credentials and view the email TotalCount.

Comment: The credentials seem to be the problem because it works if I enter the username and password of the mailbox account. What do I need to change in Exchange (or elsewhere) that would let me access from another account?